# How to know the no of text field from page generated from database having variable no of text fields

Tags: java, servlets

I have generated this html page from servlet and it has variable rows depending on data from database after filling this text field which has variable name from assign through loop I now want to save this data to database to database through servlet but the issue is how i would know how many text field are on this page 
can some explain this thing or describe a little code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>SID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Roll No.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15685</td>
      <td>sdfdsfsdf</td>
      <td><input name="stdNo0" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>999</td>
      <td>sdfdsfsdf</td>
      <td><input name="stdNo1" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have a look at this ('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637045/displaying-data-from-resultset-in-html-table')

Comment: i have done this i want to read back to the servlet and save it to database the values of text field againt sid